# PayPal iOS SDK 2.0.5 is not authenticating email id and password correctly

Tags: ios, paypal

hii everyone i am new on this professional site.actually i have a problem in PayPal iOS SDK 2.0.5. This sdk is downloaded from github and now when I tried to logged in paypal then it is not authenticating Can anyone tell that why is this happening and payment is also not transferred in business account from personal account
Thankx 
Please help me

here is the link 
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/archive/master.zip

```
    #define kPayPalEnvironment PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork

       @interface ZZMainViewController ()

       @property(nonatomic, strong, readwrite) IBOutlet UIButton *payNowButton;
       @property(nonatomic, strong, readwrite) IBOutlet UIButton *payFutureButton;
       @property(nonatomic, strong, readwrite) IBOutlet UIView *successView;

       @property(nonatomic, strong, readwrite) PayPalConfiguration *payPalConfig;

       @end

       @implementation ZZMainViewController

       - (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      self.title = @"PayPal SDK Demo";

      // Set up payPalConfig
     _payPalConfig = [[PayPalConfiguration alloc] init];
     _payPalConfig.acceptCreditCards = YES;
     _payPalConfig.languageOrLocale = @"en";
     _payPalConfig.merchantName = @"Awesome Shirts, Inc.";
     _payPalConfig.merchantPrivacyPolicyURL = [NSURL    URLWithString:@"https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/ua/privacy-full"];
     _payPalConfig.merchantUserAgreementURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/ua/useragreement-full"];

    // Setting the languageOrLocale property is optional.
    //
    // If you do not set languageOrLocale, then the PayPalPaymentViewController will present
    // its user interface according to the device's current language setting.
    //
    // Setting languageOrLocale to a particular language (e.g., @"es" for Spanish) or
    // locale (e.g., @"es_MX" for Mexican Spanish) forces the PayPalPaymentViewController
    // to use that language/locale.
     //
          // For full details, including a list of available languages and locales, see   PayPalPaymentViewController.h.

        _payPalConfig.languageOrLocale = [NSLocale preferredLanguages][0];

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.successView.hidden = YES;

        // use default environment, should be Production in real life
        self.environment = kPayPalEnvironment;

        NSLog(@"PayPal iOS SDK version: %@", [PayPalMobile libraryVersion]);

     }

     - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewWillAppear:YES];

        // Preconnect to PayPal early
        [PayPalMobile preconnectWithEnvironment:self.environment];
    }

     #pragma mark - Receive Single Payment

    - (IBAction)pay {
     // Remove our last completed payment, just for demo purposes.
     self.resultText = nil;

    PayPalPayment *payment = [[PayPalPayment alloc] init];
    payment.amount = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:@"9.95"];
    payment.currencyCode = @"USD";
    payment.shortDescription = @"Hipster t-shirt";

     if (!payment.processable) {
    // This particular payment will always be processable. If, for
    // example, the amount was negative or the shortDescription was
    // empty, this payment wouldn't be processable, and you'd want
    // to handle that here.
    }

      // Update payPalConfig re accepting credit cards.
      self.payPalConfig.acceptCreditCards = self.acceptCreditCards;

       PayPalPaymentViewController *paymentViewController = [[PayPalPaymentViewController alloc] initWithPayment:payment
                                                                                                  configuration:self.payPalConfig
                                                                                                        delegate:self];
  [self presentViewController:paymentViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
   }



      - (void)payPalPaymentViewController:(PayPalPaymentViewController *)paymentViewController didCompletePayment:(PayPalPayment *)completedPayment {
       NSLog(@"PayPal Payment Success!");
       self.resultText = [completedPayment description];
       [self showSuccess];

        [self sendCompletedPaymentToServer:completedPayment]; // Payment was processed    successfully; send to server for verification and fulfillment
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
   }

      - (void)payPalPaymentDidCancel:(PayPalPaymentViewController *)paymentViewController {
       NSLog(@"PayPal Payment Canceled");
       self.resultText = nil;
        self.successView.hidden = YES;
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
   }

      #pragma mark Proof of payment validation

     - (void)sendCompletedPaymentToServer:(PayPalPayment *)completedPayment {
      // TODO: Send completedPayment.confirmation to server
         NSLog(@"Here is your proof of payment:\n\n%@\n\nSend this to your server for c  onfirmation   and fulfillment.", completedPayment.confirmation);
       }


      #pragma mark - Authorize Future Payments

      - (IBAction)getUserAuthorization:(id)sender {

          PayPalFuturePaymentViewController *futurePaymentViewController =      [[PayPalFuturePaymentViewController alloc] initWithConfiguration:self.payPalConfig delegate:self];
      [self presentViewController:futurePaymentViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
      }


      #pragma mark PayPalFuturePaymentDelegate methods

       - (void)payPalFuturePaymentViewController:(PayPalFuturePaymentViewController *)futurePaymentViewController didAuthorizeFuturePayment:(NSDictionary   *)futurePaymentAuthorization {
      NSLog(@"PayPal Future Payment Authorization Success!");
     self.resultText = futurePaymentAuthorization[@"code"];
     [self showSuccess];

     [self sendAuthorizationToServer:futurePaymentAuthorization];
      [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
       }

         - (void)payPalFuturePaymentDidCancel:(PayPalFuturePaymentViewController      *)futurePaymentViewController {
          NSLog(@"PayPal Future Payment Authorization Canceled");
         self.successView.hidden = YES;
         [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
     }

     - (void)sendAuthorizationToServer:(NSDictionary *)authorization {
     // TODO: Send authorization to server
      NSLog(@"Here is your authorization:\n\n%@\n\nSend this to your server to complete future payment setup.", authorization);
    }


    #pragma mark - Helpers

      - (void)showSuccess {
       self.successView.hidden = NO;
       self.successView.alpha = 1.0f;
      [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
       [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [UIView setAnimationDelay:2.0];
       self.successView.alpha = 0.0f;
       [UIView commitAnimations];
     }

     #pragma mark - Flipside View Controller

      - (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(ZZFlipsideViewController *)controller {
       if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
       [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
       }    else {
        [self.flipsidePopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
         self.flipsidePopoverController = nil;
        }
     }

     - (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
       self.flipsidePopoverController = nil;
       }

      - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
       if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"pushSettings"]) {
      [[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self];

           if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            UIPopoverController *popoverController = [(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue popoverController];
             self.flipsidePopoverController = popoverController;
          popoverController.delegate = self;
          }
        }
      }

         - (IBAction)togglePopover:(id)sender {
        if (self.flipsidePopoverController) {
         [self.flipsidePopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
         self.flipsidePopoverController = nil;
       } else {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showAlternate" sender:sender];
       }
      }

  @end
```

Comment: Where is your code? (facepalm)

Comment: actually this sdk is logged any email and user id...i downloaded this sdk from https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/mobile-sdk-overview/ here

Comment: Dave from PayPal here.

It looks like you're simply trying to run the Sample App that comes with the PayPal iOS SDK, right? At least, that is the code that you have pasted into your question.

If that's the case, please provide the specific steps that you are following when running the app, and show where the behavior is not what you'd expect.

Or, if you have integrated the SDK into your own app, please show the relevant code (from your app). And then, please provide the specific steps that you are following when running the app, and show where the behavior is not what you'd expect.

Thanks!

Comment: yes you r right i am just trying to run the sample app that comes with the paypal ios SDK and when i run this app then it is asking for the email id and password and when i enters anything in these two boxes then it accepts that. Now i want to know that why is this not authenticating email id and password, why this not giving the error message  of wrong email id and password.

Comment: actually i am implementing the paypal first time so i dont have much idea on this so kindly guide me Thanku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not authenticating the email and password because you have your environment set to PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork. Setting it to NoNetwork sets it to a "mock" environment and just simulates the actions.  You'll need to set the environment to either Live or Sandbox in order to process/authenticate with those environments.  The below code is the relevant snippet that you need to look at...

```
// Set the environment:
// - For live charges, use PayPalEnvironmentProduction (default).
// - To use the PayPal sandbox, use PayPalEnvironmentSandbox.
// - For testing, use PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork.
#define kPayPalEnvironment PayPalEnvironmentSandbox
```